# newbie question basic syntax to call field (active record) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning some basic in rails, and found a difficulty in understanding a code.

I have this method

```
def mymethod
  cup  = Cup.find_by_id(current_cup.id)
  result, log = cup.parse(mug.bought_date)
end
```

There are two questions that I have for the code above

The cup is taking the value based on id with the parameter of current cup id. But I got lost with result, log because I can"t find "result, log" function for rails in google (or maybe I miss it). Or maybe it is a defined function ? 
the second question is that, in the mysql table, I don"t find any columns of "parse". Howcome the cup.parse is called if there is no "parse" columns in cup row? Is it, again, a defined function by the coder, if yes, how can I make those kind of function?

Sorry for this super basic question, but I tried to read and can"t find the proper explanation. But I believe that learning directly from the experts can help me to the correct path.

Thank you so much

Comment: result,log is not a function. They are two variables and two values are returned from cup.parse and they are assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cup` model must have a method called `parse`.  Look in `app/models/cup.rb` and you should see a `def parse` in there.  Rails models expose database columns as methods, yes, but you can also add methods that dont correspond to the database at all.  This is because a model class is a just a ruby class like any other ruby class.

The second part confusing you is called destructuring assignment.  `cup.parse` returns an array with 2 elements.  You can use that syntax to pull the values out of the returned array and assigned to local variables.  For example:

```
var1, var2, var3 = [:a, :b, :c]
puts var1 #=> a
puts var2 #=> b
puts var3 #=> c
```

This pattern allows a method to return mutliple values, what are then easily assigned to local variables.

Comment: Actually, on the "methods not related to database at all", I'd even say it's better when adding custom code in ActiveRecord models to avoid conflicting with the database... Because when you do, you have a high risk of very hard to troubleshoot runtime errors :)